# "Who's that pokemon?" animated blue star with many points?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I can't find a proper way to make that thing, I've spent 6 hours trying to make something that works, but could not manage to accomplish anything besides giving up and downloading an already made template. I found a way, with compositing and an emissive node to make an orb that looks like the dark blue part of the star behind the pokemon. Could not find a proper way to animate the thing. What am I missing?

Had to edit the post for lack of clarity. Here's a YouTube link to the meme template I'm trying to replicate:

https://youtu.be/vu_zg45ONA0

[image: who's that pokemon]

The big blue animated element on the left is what gives me issues. I figured out the shading, but I don't know, and can't find a way to make something like that move like in the YouTube video. The answer I'm looking for is any way or list of possible ways to replicate the blue thing on that video. I could even remake the whole scene from scratch to try new stuff.

After making the orange background with a particle emitter, I added an icosphere, in a second layer, with no lights, no shadows, only a simple emissive blue material on the sphere, in their own collection. With compositing I can make the blue ico render with a solid blue color, overlayed on the animated background. The problem is that I can't find a quick way to animate it's vertices to make it look like the blue thing on the YouTube video. I mostly played around with the warp modifier and a random noise texture. But the surface of the icosphere only gets deformed in weird ways and never in the way I need.

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Obviously only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe in detail what the issue is, supported by [accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: A 2D version of this "spotlight" can be fairly easily created and animated with Geometry Nodes. It's a circle with heavily distorted edge vertices.

Comment: Here is the GN setup for this spotlight "circle": https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0tSq.jpg and here's an example of the animation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg5Fc.gif It's two circles, one for the dark blue outer area and one for the inner light-blue area. The base object for the GN can be anything. For example, just use the default cube, add the GN modifier and adjust the settings in the modifier's panel.

Answer (score 1):

I agree exactly with @Blunder: do it with *Geometry Nodes*!

[image]

This is how I do it:

[image]

Here I simply use the node `Scene Time` and create with it in combination with the positions of the points of a circle, a vector for the node `Noise Texture`.

This in turn creates a value for scaling the position vector, which I redefine with the node `Set Position`.

The curve is then converted to a mesh with `Fill Curve`.

Finally you can create the visual effect with *Freestyle*.

[image]